# Flutter jitsi meet not work on release apk

Tags: android, flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet, release-apk

My flutter application does not work when building for android release (apk). I found a solution on the internet that says to try proguard, which i added to my build.gradle file.

```
 minifyEnabled true
 useProguard true
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

`flutter run --release` gives this error on the command line

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_ary1ueujmxi5fq4lgejl14cx4.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_ary1ueujmxi5fq4lgejl14cx4$_run_closure2) values: [build_ary1ueujmxi5fq4lgejl14cx4$_run_closure2@26ab8bee]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           11.4s
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Have you added required pro-guard rules for Jitsy if any

Comment: yes i added in proguard-rules.pro in android/app